# Restrict clone depth for all pull/fetch to 20k for Git

Tags: git, git-clone

I must restrict the depth at which our source code is checked out for many reasons.

I'm aware of the ability to pull in git with a specified depth using `git pull --depth 3`, but I'm looking for a way to default the depth of checkout to 20k commits or some arbitrary number of commits.

It would be even better if there was a way to restrict the pulling of commits older than a specific date.

Comment: It's not possible to restrict depth on the server side. The only thing you can do on the server side is split the repo into two with old commits and new. Cutting old commits from new require rewriting history.

Comment: Can you share any of the reasons you need to do this? We might be able to suggest a useful workaround, but (as it's currently written) I think this question might be too general to answer well.

Comment: I'm helping with a transition from CVS. We're five years into the transition and have had extreme pushback. So much so that we're syncing our CVS changes to git, and we've created workarounds to CVS CLI to make it more Git-like. Additionally, management has hesitations with Git as the entire history is downloaded on every clone of the repository.

Comment: Well just create one git repository containing the history of the project up until some fixed point (which won't change) and let everyone use that repository

Answer (score 0):

There is no support within Git to restrict or protect older commits than a specific point (be it date or specific sha).

As a fellow commenter pointed out, you could create one git repository containing the history of the project up until some fixed point (which won't change) then create a second repository without the history and let everyone use that repository (src: [dan1st-is-crying](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10871900/dan1st-is-crying))